# Can't connect to k8s service with React

Tags: reactjs

I have a React client that connects to a server via a k8s service. Locally I have checked everything and it works when the url is localhost and I'm just running the client on port 3000 and the server on port 5000.

When I put this in kubernetes in GKE this will not work so to connect between a client pod on port 3000 and a server pod on port 5000 I need a service.

I am very grateful to for helping me debug my k8s on this question [k8s SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605299/pod-not-communicating-with-service-in-gke?noredirect=1#comment123034082_69605299), but we were even execing into a client pod, creating a main.js file that calls fetch at url http://server-cluster-ip-service:5000 and receiving the correct json - and I have since checked again with improved React and server code, and this definitely works, but when I put the url in a fetch request on the client, the fetch request gets:

VM66:1 GET http://server-cluster-ip-service:5000/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

The problem has to be React. I am using React Hooks in a create-react-app project. I have a Home component and an EditUser component inside a Pages folder. I'm using React routing with

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

could the routing be messing up the fetch request?

The error displayed on the Network panel is a CORS error
[image: CORS error]

but I'm not sure how to stop this?

client:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./editUser.css";

function EditUser() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const getAllUsers = async () => {
    console.log("GETTING ALL USERS");
    fetch("http://server-cluster-ip-service:5000",
        {
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
            }
        }
    )
      .then((res) => res)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("DATA", data);
        setUsers(data);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 data-position="header">Merr k8s testbed</h1>

      <section data-position="quotes">
        <h2>Console</h2>
        <ul>
          {users &&
            users.map((user) => (
              <li>
                <h3>{user.id}</h3>
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EditUser;
```

server:

const express = require("express");

var cors = require("cors");

const PORT = 5000;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.listen(PORT, function () {
console.log("listening on ", PORT);
});

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("PROCESSING GET USERS REQUEST");
  const list = [
    { id: 1, firstName: "item1" },
    { id: 2, firstName: "item2" },
    { id: 3, firstName: "item3" },
  ];
  res.send(list);
});
```

Comment: Nothing in the question as currently written indicates a CORS problem. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is a DNS error. What’s shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2fCI.png indicates that the request is not being sent successfully — it shows there is no response. That is, the request is not even reaching the Express server at all.

Comment: Can you open http://server-cluster-ip-service:5000 URL in a browser?

Comment: I can't open it in a browser I'm afraid. I sent a request directly from the client pod to the server pod tho and it worked fine?

Comment: Is the request being sent from the browser through my ingress and not from the pod?

Comment: Is it likely to be something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944651/react-w-kubernetes-deployed-api-giving-cors-error